# Проблема с удалением конкретного элемента из контейнера array

Tags: c++11

Задан массив из `k` символов. Вычислить сумму `S` первых `20` отрицательных элементов массива, кратных `5`. Удалить из массива элементы, значения которых равны по абсолютному значению `S`.

Вот версия программы, которая выполняет нахождение суммы и ищет элементы, по модулю равные `S`, но 29 строке нет никакого тела после `if`, потому что не представляю, как удалить из array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    setlocale (0,"Rus");
    int i,j=0,sum=0;
    const int k=40;
    array <int, k> arr={};                      // Создается массив, все элементы которого инициализированы нулями


    for(i=0;i<k;i++){
        arr[i]=-200+rand()%300;                 
        cout<<arr[i]<<endl;
    }


    for(i=0;i<k,j<20;i++){
        if(arr[i]<0&&arr[i]%5==0)
            sum+=arr[i];                    //  Сумма 20 отрицательных элементов
            j++;
    }

    for(i=0;i<k;i++){
        if(arr[i]==sum||arr[i]==-sum)
        //    arr[i]
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте в вопрос свои попытки решить задачу. [**Аргументация, почему это нужно**](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/). Спасибо.

Comment: Контейнер `array` имеет фиксированный размер, задающийся на этапе компиляции, и не поддерживает операцию удаления. Если надо удалять, то используйте `vector`.

Comment: очень жаль( в лабораторной сказано выполнить вышеуказанное задание, используя последовательный контейнер array.
А может есть хитрый способ как-то обойти это? не совсем удалить как-нибудь, может удалить в тайне. Ну очень нужно сделать так, как в задании

Comment: в условии задачи сказано использовать std::array или там просто сказано использовать массив?

Comment: в условии сказано выполнить задание, используя последовательный контейнер array

Comment: тогда пишите `using seq_array = std::vector<int>;` и дело в шляпе.